# Localization xliff error message

Tags: java, android, xml, string, xliff

I've created a resource string with an *xliff* but I get an error when I run the application:

```
Error:(17, 52) Error: The prefix "id" for attribute "id:" associated with an element type "xliff:g" is not bound.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\msanli\AndroidStudioProjects\JustJava\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:17:52: Error: The prefix "id" for attribute "id:" associated with an element type "xliff:g" is not bound.
```

I have already added this near my resources so I'm not sure what's going on

`(xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2").`

Any help is appreciated !

Resources:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="app_name">Just Java</string>
    <string name="hint_name">Name</string>
    <string name="toppings_header">Toppings</string>
    <string name="whipped_cream">Whipped Cream</string>
    <string name="chocolate">Chocolate</string>
    <string name="quantity_header">Quantity</string>
    <string name="decrement_minus">-</string>
    <string name="quantity_text">1</string>
    <string name="increment_plus">+</string>
    <string name="order_text">Order</string>
    <string name="max_coffee_toast">You cannot have more than 100 cups of coffee</string>
    <string name="min_coffee_toast">You cannot have less than 1 cup of coffee</string>
    <string name="admin_email"></string>
    <string name="email_order_subject">Just Java Order Summary For </string>
    <string name="name_order_summary">
        Name: <xliff:g id:="name" example="Samuel">%s</xliff:g>
    </string>
    <string name="whipped_cream_ordered">Add Whipped Cream? </string>
    <string name="chocolate_ordered">Add Chocolate? </string>
    <string name="quantity">Quantity: </string>
    <string name="total_price">Total Price: $</string>
    <string name="thank_you">Thank You!</string>



</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your resources are not valid XML: try removing the colon in `id:="name"` and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with a very similar problem for hours.
If you have generated a strings.xml file for another language using the Translations Editor, you will need to put the `(xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2")` on the new xml file as well. Otherwise you will get a `The prefix ”xliff“ for element ”xliff:g“ is not bound` error. I hope this helps other people who might be googling this still.

Answer (score 0):

So strings in strings.xml behaves a little differently from regular strings.
You need to escape(delimit) certain characters. You can save the below table.

Replace `&gt;` for <
Replace `&lt;` for >
Replace `&amp;` for & 
Replace `"'"` for ' 
Replace `&quot` for \"\"

So in your case, it is looking at "&gt;xliff:g" .

Follow this for > as well. This should fix your issue. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding the table you suggested... Which characters in my the strings.xml file need to be escaped?

Comment: made changes . this should make more sense.